# Dropzone form won't display

Tags: django, dropzone.js

I'm trying to add the dropzone form to a django template and it won't show up. I've imported using django's static and downloaded the dist folder from http://www.dropzonejs.com/ and used

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

as instructed by the website.

```
<html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <script src="{% static '/dropzone/dropzone.js' %}"></script>
    <link href="{% static '/dropzone/dropzone.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static '/dropzone/basic.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<body>

    <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">

    </form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

I know it's not an issue with static in django because I have bootstrap working using static within this project. Any idea as to why dropzone won't display?

Answer (score 0):

try initialize the dropzone using jquery

```
 <script>
   $(".dropzone").dropzone();
</script>
```